# 401 error in postman, when i m trying to get token_id from REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, payment, http-status-code-401

I m the following document to set up the API to do the transaction in my WordPress site so, I try to test in Postman but it shows blank, and status: 401 error(Check on the figure), I m not sure what I m doing wrong I have tried to put the username, password, and module, in the header but it's not working.

[image: SC Of Documentation]

[image: Postman Header]

[image: Postman Auth]

Comment: Is your get-token api public?

Comment: Yes, it should because this is just UAT.

Comment: @VinhNT Do you have any Idea about encoding value in base64? Thanks

Comment: We don't need to encode the value in header. And because you are sending credentials value via header, so, that mean, server doesn't recognize it, and it will treat your request as Unauthorized.